# DLNA and Routing

Tags: networking, routing, dlna

I've got a DLNA (minidlna) server on one subnet (192.168.1.0/24) and a DLNA render on another subnet (192.168.2.0/24).  I've successfully used smcroute to route the multicast SSDP packets to and from each subnet.  Thus, my DLNA render discovers the DLNA server just fine.  However, the render cannot see any of the content hosted on the DLNA server.  The server seems to work fine, renders on 192.168.1.0/24 can use it as expected.  I thought UDP broadcast was involved, but `tcpdump -i eth1 -vv dst 192.168.1.255` and `tcpdump -i wlan0 -vv dst 192.168.2.255` on the router don't show any broadcast packets (except those for Syncthing), and the only multicast traffic I can see is for SSDP, which looks like it's working fine.  I can reach the "MiniDLNA status" page just fine from the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet.  What am I missing?

Please don't suggest I bridge the two interfaces, I know I can, I don't want to for QoS reasons.  Also, I know I can use a VPN layer-2 bridge, and will if I hit a dead-end here, but would prefer some routing/proxying magic if at all possible.